# Коммуникация фрейма с окном через JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть чужой сайт, в iframe которого открыта страница моего сайта. Мой JS открывает (`window.open`) новое окно с другой страницей с моего же сайта. По событию в этом окне надо "сообщить" в исходный фрейм о событии, и затем закрыть это окно.

Реализуема ли такая схема?

Не понимаю, как из окна что-то сообщить в "породивший" фрейм.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что на чужом сайте встроен фрейм на вашу страницу, а уже на вашей странице открывается окно. В окне происходит событие, дальше кто должен получить ответ? Чужой сайт или ваш сайт?

Comment: Ответ должен получить мой сайт: та его страница, открытая во фрейме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался: `self.opener` адресует окно, породившее данное.

Т.е. по событию, в "новом окне" работает примерно такой код:

```
/* из окна вызываем метод "родителя", в данном случае это тот iframe */
self.opener.receiver("в новом окне произошло событие!"); 
self.close();
```

В оригинальной странице, которая в iframe, описание этого метода, "приёмника":

```
function receiver( msg){
    alert( msg);
}
```